# Increasing the SSD on Dell chromebook 3380

Tags: dell, chromebook

Anyone knows if the Dell Chromebook 13 3380 still has an upgradeable SSD? Most chromebooks now have the SSD on board.

I was meant to buy a 3380 device, replace the 16GB SSD with a 128 one and install Ubuntu,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware question that is best answered by the manufacture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this site it can't be upgrade
https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/ssd-upgrades/dell/chromebook/13-3380